# Access to admin/people/create is DISABLED

Tags: users

I am using Drupal 7.24. After I disabled these modules `Checklist API, Connector and Features`. I got this message `Access to admin/people/create is DISABLED.`. And when I go to admin/peope/create, the email and password fields are pre-filled with user 1 email and password. How can I resolve this issue. Are the modules I just disabled related with this issue?

Anyone please help me resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The pre-filled is because your cache browser and properly you check `admin/people/create` by no `user=1` .
There are 2 please to  effect registration
 one :
 `admin/config/people/accounts`
**Registration and cancellation**
Who can register accounts?

- Administrators only
- Visitors
- Visitors, but administrator   approval is required

and anther in `admin/people/permissions`

**User**
`Administer permissions`
Warning: Give to trusted roles only; this permission has security implications.

`Administer users`
Warning: Give to trusted roles only; this permission has security implications.

.

check 2 this place and make sure you select correct(according you application ) and correct permission. your problem not dependency on module disabling :)

Comment: I clear the caches and check the user permissions. All the permissions are ok and in `Who can register accounts`, `Visitors, but admin approval is required` is selected. But still I got the message `Access to admin/people/create is DISABLED.` and the fields are still pre-filled.

Comment: @rongok with which user role check this?

Comment: I check it with administrator role. Also my user id is 1.

Comment: @rongok I suggest try to enable disabled module and tell me if the problem exist  ?

Comment: Problem still exist. I tried enable/disable the modules. I don't think the above mention modules are not related with the issue. Whenever I clear the caches, the message appear alternately.

Comment: @rongok It is right ,this problem not related to modules that you install/uninstall .
Do you have custom module that in it implemented  `hook_alter_menu`?

Comment: I have custom modules that implement `hook_menu` and `hook_permission` but no `hook_alter_menu`. Although the message say `Access to admin/people/create is DISABLED.` I can still access the page and create new users. Anyway, thank you for your time and replies.

Comment: @rongok you mean you can access  `admin/people/create`page but show u a message that say `Access to admin/people/create is DISABLED` ?

Comment: Yes, I can access `admin/people/create`